# how can I set up my site to default to a different url

Tags: php, cakephp

My website is http://localhost/carsales/  I have finished my cakephp website but my index page is http://localhost/carsales/car_sales/specials   , but when I type it in the format
http://localhost/carsales/  i get an error saying that i am missing a carsales controller or model..

How can I modify it so that if someone types http://localhosr/carsales/ that it shows what is in http://localhost/carsales/car_sales/specials ?. I was reading about re-route but maybe I did something wrong because its not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `routes.php` to specify the desired controller and action for the default `/` route:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'car_sales', 'action' => 'specials'));
```

Comment: Thank you I changed but its telling me Missing Controller Error: CarSales could not be found. CarSales is the name of the website (project).. and it shows the default cake php error page..

Comment: Well, what is your controller name? Just put in there whatever you usually put in there when creating links to an action in that controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about CakePHP, but I know in CodeIgniter there is a default controller setting in the routing file.  Have you looked for a similar function in Cake? If there is, you could set it to automatically route to your /car_sales controller.  There is a nice explanation of this [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Frank/2009/11/02/cakephp-s-routing-explained).  Alternatively, assuming you are using Apache, you could take a look at [URL rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). Hope this helps.